# Use "Program Files" directory on both 32-bit/64-bit systems with Inno Setup {pf}

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, 32bit-64bit

The constant `{pf}` is the directory of

```
C:\Program Files
```

for 32-bit systems and

```
C:\Program Files (x86)
```

for 64-bit systems.

However I want to use the directory

```
C:\Program Files
```

for both, 32 and 64-bit systems. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) like:

```
[Setup]
DefaultDirName={code:GetProgramFiles}\My Program
```

```pascal
[Code]

function GetProgramFiles(Param: string): string;
begin
  if IsWin64 then Result := ExpandConstant('{commonpf64}')
    else Result := ExpandConstant('{commonpf32}')
end;
```

Though this approach should only be used, if you generate binaries for the respective platform on the fly. Like in your case, if understand correctly, you compile the Java binaries for the respective architecture.

---

You can also use [64-bit install mode](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls).

Then you can simply use [`{autopf}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=autopf) (previously `{pf}`):

```
[Setup]
DefaultDirName={autopf}\My Program
```

---

If you have a separate 32-bit and 64-bit binaries in the installer, use a script like:

```
[Files]
Source: "MyDll32.dll"; DestDir: "{pf32}\My Program"; Check: not IsWin64
Source: "MyDll64.dll"; DestDir: "{pf64}\My Program"; Check: IsWin64
```

See also:

- [Is it possible to set the install mode in Inno Setup (32 or 64 bit)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9788252/850848)
- [Inno Setup 32bit and 64bit dll installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17944516/850848)

Answer (score 7):

If you are using a single installer for both 64 and 32 bit installs then you should be using the `ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode` Setup Directive. This will change {pf} and other scripted constants to be their 64 bit version when installing on a 64 bit system, and their 32 bit versions when installing on a 32 bit system.

You will obviously also want to use a Check as in Martin's example to make sure you are only installing the correct binaries.

Ex:

```
#define MyAppName "MyAwesomeApp"
[Setup]
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
AppName={#MyAppName}
DefaultDirname={pf}\{#MyAppName}

[Files]
Source: "MyApp_32bit.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check not Is64BitinstallMode;
Source: "MyApp_64bit.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check Is64BitinstallMode;
```